# Javascript card credentials verification problem

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I need to make a page that verifies the credentials on a credit card(Visa) for a project. I have created the javascript and html needed but I think I'm not tying the together well. I also have this error message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjBYd.png)
I believe the code should be alright but please correct me if it's bad. I am prety new to javascript.

```js
   
function vNumarCard(numar)
{
  var cardno = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;
  if(numar.match(cardno))
        {
      return true;
        }
      else
        {
        alert("Numarul cardului este invalid!");
        return false;
        }
}

function vDataExp(data){
    if(!data.match(/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[/][0-9]{2}/)){
        alert("Data expirarii este invalida");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        var d = new Date();
        var anCurent = d.getFullYear();
        var lunaCurenta = d.getMonth() + 1;
  
        var parti = expira.split('/');
        var an = parseInt(parti[1], 10) + 2000;
        var luna = parseInt(parti[0], 10);
  
         if (an < anCurent || (an == anCurent && luna < lunaCurenta)) {
             alert("Card expirat!")
             result = false;
         }

}
    return true;
}

function vCVC(cvc){
    if(!cvc.match(/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/)){
        alert("CVC incorect!");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

function verCard(numar,data,cvc){
    if(vNumarCard(numar)==true&&vDataExp(data)==true&&vCVC(cvc)==true){
        location.href = "success.html";
    }
}

function verDate(){
    var numar = document.getElementsByName("numarCard").value;
    var data = document.getElementsByName("dataExp").value;
    var cvc = document.getElementsByName("codCVC").value;

    verCard(numar.value,data.value,cvc.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">
<head>
 <title>Cumpara</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.css">
 
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark justify-content-center">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Acasă</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="modele.html">Modele</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="categorii.html">Categorii</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Galerie</a>
     </li>
     <li class = "nav-item">
      <a href="cos.html" class = "nav-link">
               <span class="glyphicon">&#128722;</span>
             </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    
 </nav>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <h2 style="text-align: center;">Cumpara produsele selectate</h2>
   <form method="POST">
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">
      Email:
     </label>
     <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
     
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="numeCumparator">
      Nume:
     </label>
     <input type="text" name="numeCumparator" class="form-control" placeholder="Nume">
     
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="numarCard">
      Numar Card:
     </label>
     <input type="text" name="numarCard" class="form-control" placeholder="1234 1234 1234 1234">
     
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="dataExp">
      Data de expirare:
     </label>
     <input type="text" name="dataExp" class="form-control" placeholder="ll/aa">
     
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="codCVC">
      CVC:
     </label>
     <input type="text" name="codCVC" class="form-control" placeholder="CVC">
     
    </div>
    <button name="cumpara" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" onclick="verDate();">Cumpara</button>
   </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
 </div>
</div>


<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripturi/cumpara.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName()` returns a node list, not a single item. Change

```
var numar = document.getElementsByName("numarCard").value;
```

(and the other two, similar lines), to:

```
var numar = document.getElementsByName("numarCard")[0].value;
```

or

```
var numar = document.querySelector("[name=numarCard]").value;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed it. And thanks for explaining what getElementByName actually does. But I now seem to have ran into another problem that I can't figure out, All the functions return the correct value when called but I cannot change the page to success.html (location.href = "success.html") . I have used the same line to change other pages but it doesn't seem to work here. I have also tried with document.location.href and window.location but I get the same result.

Comment: I'd post that up as a separate question. And check to confirm there's no JS errors, and that the area that's doing the redirect is definitely running.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did as you said and posted another question with the problem.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971738/cannot-redirect-using-javascript